# May HighPriority Roaming Settings be hierarchical containers

Tags: windows, uwp, win-universal-app, application-settings

In the documentation there are only samples where the **high priority** node in the settings is a `ApplicationDataCompositeValue`:

```
ApplicationDataContainer roamingSettings =  ApplicationData.Current.RoamingSettings;
roamingSettings.Values["HighPriority"] = "Sample_High_Priority_value";
ApplicationDataCompositeValue composite = new ApplicationDataCompositeValue();
composite["HP_settingName1"] = 1; // example value
composite["HP_settingName2"] = "world"; // example value

roamingSettings.Values["HighPriority"] = composite;
```

***May this node be also a container which is also synced at high priority?***

```
    Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataContainer container = 
       ApplicationData.Current.RoamingSettings.CreateContainer("HighPriority",
       Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataCreateDisposition.Always);
```

This would allow a better hierarchical structuring of the high priority data. (container may be nested to maximum of 32 levels in regarding of the quota)

Answer (score 1):

> May this node be also a container which is also synced at high priority?

No. High priority roaming works only with one setting, if you need to roam multiple pieces of data such as an article and a page number you can use a [composite value](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdatacompositevalue.aspx).

Ref [Roaming your app data](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsappdev/2012/07/17/roaming-your-app-data/):

> To meet these customer needs we created a unique setting name that is specifically designed to handle this experience, HighPriority. To use it, simply name your setting HighPriority in **the root container of the RoamingSettings**. It is used like any other setting. The roaming engine allows this setting to roam much more quickly than other roaming data so you can deliver on that experience.

As described above, "HighPriority" is just a special key in the roaming settings we can use for data we need to sync immediately and it only works in the root container of the [RoamingSettings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.roamingsettings.aspx), so it can't work with a child application settings container in [RoamingSettings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.roamingsettings.aspx).

The HighPriority setting is designed to store a **small amount** of data that will be roamed out to the cloud with higher priority than other roaming data. The size of HighPriority setting must be **under 8KB** in order to retain the HighPriority benefits. Exceeding 8KB will not cause errors, but it will be roamed as if it were a normal setting.